# std::cin of char causing infinite loop

Tags: c++

I've used the cout statement after the cin's before the switch to determine that I'm having a problem with the second number and the character op and for some reason I get into an infinite loop!!! 
I have a feeling that I'm making a small mistake in the syntax but I cant figure out what is it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float a, b;
    char op, ans;
    do {
    cout << "Enter first number, operator, second number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> op;
    cout << "first number is: " << a << "second number is: " << b << "operator is: " << op;
    switch (op) {
    case '/':
        cout << "answer = " << a / b << endl;
        break;
    case '*':
        cout << "answer = " << a * b << endl;
        break;
    case '+':
        cout << "answer = " << a + b << endl;
        break;
    case '-':
        cout << "answer = " << a - b << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << "again? Y/N";
    cin >> ans;
    } while (ans != 'N' || ans != 'n');

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A popular mistake: cin >> a >> b >> op; is fine, but if(cin) is missing - besides the while answers below

Comment: It's a bit late, but please take future care to utilize the title. Code not working properly is in a ton of the questions on this site and C++ is in the tags, so the title really adds no value and definitely does not help when others with the same problem search for solutions.

Answer (score 6):

ans will ALWAYS not equal EITHER n or N.  Your OR condition is always going to pass as true.  Try switching this to

```
    while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y')
```

Comment: `while (ans != 'N' && ans != 'n')` would work as well.

Comment: @cHao: As remyabel pointed out just seconds after user3112926's answer. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Heh...stuff happens fast on the easy questions.  :)

Comment: Ok I did that. Now I'm not in an infinite loop anymore however, I still have a problem with the second number and the char op. The second number is -1.0034e+008 and op is a weired symbol.Also, while there's no infinite loop anymore, I cannot  choose to run the program again. I get the messeage "again? Y/N" , but after I'm already done with the program at this point. Beneath it there's already "the press any key to continue" sentence

Comment: your cins are out of order from your prompting.  Your prompt calls for a op b, but your cin order is a b op.

Comment: Yub that was it user3112926. I had my cins are out of order. Thanx a lot man.

Answer (score 4):

You want your condition to be:

```
} while (ans != 'N' && ans != 'n');
```

It can't not be 'N' and 'n' simultaneously. If that were the case, the world would probably disappear into a vortex of doom.

Comment: "can't not be", did you intend on a double negative?

Comment: @Bobby High five on having the same helmet.

Comment: @BobbyDigital: The double negative is correct. I tripped over it too and would probably rephrase, but it's correct...

Comment: Yeah, you meant it; sorry.

Comment: I dunno.  It seems to need another negative in there somewhere.  "Can't not be unequal to"?  Truth be told, though, i can't be sure whether the explanation is for the problem or the solution, so i might be misinterpreting.  But as far as `ans` goes, it certainly *could* not be `'N'` and `'n'` at the same time; all it'd have to do is be `'y'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from this line:
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> op;

to this one:
    cin >> a;
    cin >> op;
    cin >> b;