# C++ do-while loop won't quit even once the condition is met

Tags: c++

So most of my program works fine. It is a program designed to estimate sine and cosine values using Taylor series. The program is designed to quit once the user inputs `0`, and then `"Y"` or `"y"` upon being asked if they are sure. The char variable `exit` is initialized to `"n"`, and then is changed if the user inputs `y`. But the loop doesn't quit then.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double calculateFACT(int n); // function that calculates the factorial
double calculateSIN(float, float); // function that approximates the sine
double calculateCOS(float, float); // function that approximates the cosine

int main()
{
    int choice; // menu choice
    double angle = 0; // angle user inputs, initialied to zero
    double calc; // the calculated sine or cosine value
    int order; // order approimation value
    char exit = 'n'; // exits for yes

    do {
        cout << "MAIN MENU" << endl;
        cout << "1. To enter the data." << endl;
        cout << "2. To calculate the sin(x)" << endl;
        cout << "3. To approximate the sin(x)" << endl;
        cout << "4. To calculate the cos(x)" << endl;
        cout << "5. To approximate the cos(x)" << endl;
        cout << "6. To re-enter data." << endl;
        cout << "Press 0 to quit." << endl;
        cout << "Please make a choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        if (choice != 0 &&
            choice != 1 &&
            choice != 2 &&
            choice != 3 &&
            choice != 4 &&
            choice != 5 &&
            choice != 6)
        {
            cout << "Wrong Choice. Only options 1-6 are available." << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "Please give a value for the angle: ";
                cin >> angle;
                cout << endl;
            }
            else cout << "Please use option 6 to enter a new angle." << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "You have to enter a value first!" << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                calc = sin(angle);
                cout << "The sine of x is " << calc << endl << endl << endl;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "You have to enter a value first!" << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please give a value for the approximation order n: ";
                cin >> order;
                cout << "The approximation of sin(" << angle << ") is: " << calculateSIN(angle, order) << endl << endl;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 4)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "You have to enter a value first!" << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                calc = cos(angle);
                cout << "The cosine of x is " << calc << endl << endl << endl;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 5)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "You have to enter a value first!" << endl << endl; // cosine function not giving the right value
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please give a value for the approximation order n: ";
                cin >> order;
                cout << "The approximation of cos(" << angle << ") is: " << calculateCOS(angle, order) << endl << endl;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 6)
        {
            if (angle == 0)
            {
                cout << "If this is the first time you run this program please choose option 1." << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please give new angle: ";
                cin >> angle;
                cout << endl << endl;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 0)
        {
            cout << exit;
            cout << endl << endl << "Are you sure you want to quit? (Y/N): "; // Y/N option doesnt work
            cin >> exit;

        }
        cout << exit;
    } while (exit != 'Y' || exit != 'y');

    if (exit == 'Y' || exit == 'y')
    {
        cout << endl << "Now quitting.." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}

double calculateFACT(int n)
{
    double nfact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        nfact *= i;
    return nfact;
}

double calculateSIN(float angle, float order)
{
    double sine = angle;
    for (int i = 1; i < order; i++)
    {
        sine += pow(-1.0, i) * (pow(angle, 2 * i + 1)) / calculateFACT(2 * i + 1);
    }
    return sine;
}

double calculateCOS(float angle, float order)
{
    double cosine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++)
    {
        cosine += pow(-1.0, i) * (pow(angle, 2 * i)) / calculateFACT(2 * i);
    }
    return cosine;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `exit != 'Y' && exit != 'y'`.

Comment: A `switch` statement would be better here or a *table lookup*.

Comment: Review the functions `toupper` and `tolower` so you only have to compare with uppercase or lowercase; not both.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a similar question named [Why is my c++ code not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670447/1508519). And the answer is exactly the same. You need to do `exit != 'Y' && exit != 'y'` otherwise it will always evaluate to true.

Comment: ohhh ok sorry for not looking at that question. I wasnt getting the logic in that, it makes sense now though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

remyabel answered the question. Your code says "if the user didn't type 'Y' or 'y'", keep running. Since you're only looking for one character, it will keep running forever, since the character cannot be both 'Y' and 'y' at the same time.

Hence, `while (exit != 'Y' && exit != 'y')` essentially says "if the user didn't type an exit condition, I'm going to keep executing."

Comment: Also, the `if` statement following the `while` is redundant because it's the same condition.

Comment: Should be a comment ...

Comment: You're right, @πάνταῥεῖ, thank you for the advice. My apologies.